# Duplicate class name in my page - get the text using cssSelector

Tags: html, css-selectors

below is my html looks like and the problem with my page is that, i have duplicate `class names` so for an example in my page i have `class="inner"` mulitple times in the same page.

My questions is: how can i grab the the text which says `Get this text` using cssSelector ?

```
<div class="tools-col-right">
       <div class="subcr">
       <div .....</div>
       <div .....</div>
       <div .....</div>
       <div class="main-inner">
       <div class="inner"> 
            <div class="t"></div>
            <h3> additional information</h3>
        <div class="subcolumns">
        <div class="subject">
            <ul>
             <li>....</li> 
             <li>....</li>
             <li>....</li>
             <li>....</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

I am trying to get the text of `div class='subject'`

tried something like this: `div[class='tools-col-right .subject']`
but does not work.

Comment: Having multiple class names isn't necessarily a problem, it's certainly allowed. You could use something *like* ".module > .inner" which will only reference .inner classes immediately inside .module ones

Comment: Who needs indentation, right? `:P`

Comment: Is that your actual HTML structure?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: i just paste the part of my html structure and i have very long html page.

Comment: @AbuHamzah You're missing a `</style>` tag. Also, why is that `<style>` element there at all? Where is his CSS code?

Comment: style tag have `background color and padding` i am not sure what does have to do with what i am looking to accomplish and i did not paste thought there is no need to be there...

Comment: okay, updated my question remove the style tag.. can we talk about solution now :)

Comment: @AbuHamzah By "get this text", do you mean select that `.inner` element so that you can apply styles to it?

Comment: Btw, why is your `".col-right"` element *inside* your `.col-left` element? That doesn't make much sense. If your structure represents a table, your left column and right column elements should be siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless ways. Which might work depends on your whole page markup (you only gave an extract of your page, with no other `.inner` elements).

```css
#ctl00_ctl00_ContentControl3_phContent .inner {…}

.about .inner {…}

.main-inner .inner {…}

#top-container .inner {…}
```

---

**EDIT** after your updated code:

Now you only have one element with the class `subject`. Again, without your whole markup (containing the other elements with the same class), it's not possible to give you a safe answer. With your example, each of the following selectors should work:

```css
.subject {…}
.subcolumns .subject {…}
.inner .subject {…}
.main-inner .subject {…}
.subcr .subject {…}
.tools-col-right .subject {…}
```

Comment: i have updated my question and try to put the html code as close as possible, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This selector would select that element:

```
.tools-col-right > .subject
```

Comment: i have updated my question, i can not modify the page and i am working on the test cases where i have no control over.